# Auto pickup dates from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, date

I am looking for some T-SQL code that should pick the date which is the "last Sunday in the month of January".

For example:

```
Current day      expected result
2017-01-29       2016-01-31
2017-02-05       2017-01-29
2017-02-19       2017-01-29
2018-01-28       2017-01-29
2018-02-04       2018-01-28
```

This is because the year starts from last Sunday in January

I have some T-SQL code which is being used in SQL Server 2014:

```
select 
    convert(varchar(10), DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, '19000107', DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, CONVERT(date, CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), GETDATE(), 112) + '0101')), 30)) / 7  * 7, '19000107'), 120)
```

If the current date is between February to December then the above code returns the correct answer. But if we set current date as '2017-01-25' (or any other dates in January), then the result is wrong.

For the above date (2017-01-25) answer should be '2016-01-31'

Comment: Either the datepart or datename functions will help you with this.

Comment: @dan-bracuk Could you able to update the T-SQL code and send them? It will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue might be that the query is finding the first day of Jan for the year supplied, but this is going to be different if Jan is the supplied month. 
The change is to determine if Jan is the supplied month, and return last year as the year.

```
select 
convert(varchar(10), DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, '19000107', DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, CONVERT(date, CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), (CASE WHEN MONTH(GetDate()) = 1 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), GetDate(), 112) - 1 ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), GetDate(), 112) END), 112) + '0101')), 30)) / 7  * 7, '19000107'), 120)
```

The `CASE` statement within the `CONVERT(date, CONVERT(VARCHAR(4)`...is where the change was made.

Comment: thanks worked. I need another T-SQL code for another scenario. The Scenario is "For the same concept I want T-SQL code to pick previous year date". For example 1. Current date is '2017-02-21', then the code should pick '2016-01-31'. For example 2. Current date is '2018-02-21', then the code should pick '2017-01-29'. Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

A lookup table is the best way to solve this type of problem

```
WITH lookup(d) AS
(
  VALUES( ('2016-01-31'),
          ('2017-01-29'),
          ('2018-01-28')
)
select MAX(d)
FROM lookup
WHERE d <= GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

The rightmost column of this will calculate the previous last Sunday in January for any date.  I've left the other columns in as a simple way to document and experiment with the logic.

There is no branching logic, it is all pure date math so it should aggregate reasonably fast and should be able to use indexes on a date column.

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = '20170205';
SELECT SampleDate= @Date  ,
    PreviousLastSundayInJanuaryForSampleDate = DATEADD(DAY,(DATEPART(WEEKDAY,EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,(DATEPART(MONTH
,DATEADD(DAY,((DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,DATEADD(DAY,(DATEPART(WEEKDAY,EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,(DATEPART(MONTH,@Date)-1)*-1,@Date)))-1)*-1,EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,(DATEPART(MONTH,@Date)-1)*-1,@Date)))))-1) * -1 ,@Date))-1)*-1
,DATEADD(DAY,((DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,DATEADD(DAY,(DATEPART(WEEKDAY,EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,(DATEPART(MONTH,@Date)-1)*-1,@Date)))-1)*-1,EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,(DATEPART(MONTH,@Date)-1)*-1,@Date)))))-1) * -1 ,@Date))))-1)*-1,EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,(DATEPART(MONTH
,DATEADD(DAY,((DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,DATEADD(DAY,(DATEPART(WEEKDAY,EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,(DATEPART(MONTH,@Date)-1)*-1,@Date)))-1)*-1,EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,(DATEPART(MONTH,@Date)-1)*-1,@Date)))))-1) * -1 ,@Date))-1)*-1
,DATEADD(DAY,((DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR,DATEADD(DAY,(DATEPART(WEEKDAY,EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,(DATEPART(MONTH,@Date)-1)*-1,@Date)))-1)*-1,EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,(DATEPART(MONTH,@Date)-1)*-1,@Date)))))-1) * -1 ,@Date))))
```

To use this against a table, replace @Date with your own date field.

Updated with sample results:

```
SampleDate  PreviousLastSundayInJanuaryForSampleDate
2008-06-03  2008-01-27
2008-12-20  2008-01-27
2009-07-08  2009-01-25
2010-01-24  2009-01-25
2010-08-12  2010-01-31
2011-02-28  2011-01-30
2011-09-16  2011-01-30
2012-04-03  2012-01-29
2012-10-20  2012-01-29
2013-05-08  2013-01-27
2013-11-24  2013-01-27
2014-06-12  2014-01-26
2014-12-29  2014-01-26
2015-07-17  2015-01-25
2016-02-02  2016-01-31
2016-08-20  2016-01-31
2017-03-08  2017-01-29
2017-09-24  2017-01-29
2018-04-12  2018-01-28
2018-10-29  2018-01-28
2019-05-17  2019-01-27
2019-12-03  2019-01-27
2020-06-20  2020-01-26
```